# how do I use the /particle effect in Minecraft education edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

exactly as the title said I was wondering if the /particle effect could be used in education edition. If it could be then I'd like to know how to use it. I can never figure out the string thing.

Comment: The wiki says yes, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Education Edition contains all Bedrock Edition features, so it also has support for `/particle`.

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/particle) the syntax is:

> `particle <effect: string> <position: x y z>`

See that page for more details.

Comment: what is effect string? I've tried and that's were i mess up!

Comment: @Clover4c679 Sorry for the really late reply. You can find a list of the particle names for BE [on the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Particles#Types_of_particles). I don't think you need the `minecraft:` namespace at the beginning as well.

Comment: thanks! still didnt work tho...